# Middleware does not get hit using router.route()

Tags: java, vert.x

I have this:

```
final Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
router.route().handler(new JWTHandler());


router.route("/").handler(ctx -> {
  HttpServerResponse response = ctx.response();
  response
    .putHeader("content-type", "text/html")
    .end("<h1>Hello from non-clustered messenger example!</h1>");
});

vertx.createHttpServer()
.requestHandler(router)
```

when I hit the "/" route I will get the "Hello from non-clustered..." response but my JWTHandler middleware will not get hit - nothing gets logged.

Did I not setup the middleware properly? I want the BodyHandler and JWTHandler middleware to run serially before my other handlers.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with this code. I tried it out, it works. Are you sure you configured the logger properly?